# How can select row in datagrid programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want select row in wpf datagrid automatically when textbox lost focus. How can I do that? I use this code but this code is not running?

```
private void txtBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGrid.SelectedIndex = 'I found index from table'
    }
```

When I run this code selected index is always = -1

Answer (score 0):

This is select the data grid row number 2. as index begin with 0

```
 int rowNumber =1;
 dataGrid.SelectedIndex = rowNumber;
```

value of the rowNumber should always be less than or equal to number of rows in datagridview

Answer (score 0):

You need to select a DataGridViewCell:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1f5d313a-203d-4e7a-ac46-eee65347a9f4/datagridview-select-cell

It looks like you want Filter a list, so I would recommend you to use a CollectionViewSource (or similar) and Databinding instead.

Search for DataBinding and DataGrid

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void txtBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGrid.Rows(index).Selected = True
    }
```

If you know the index, it should work.